# I want to prepare for the Putnam competition being completely new.

Tags: contest-math, self-learning

I have been reading a lot of resources but it seems a little too difficult for me to grasp, I have no background in mathematical competitions and the activities in my college related to competitive math are really limited. Can anyone give me a list of books or pages to start from the very basics to build my way up to the real problems?